# How to set proper google oauth client scope that don't need any access right of end user data?

Tags: google-sheets, gspread

I am learning to access Google Sheets using Python (c/q gspread)
my current script is as simple as one from [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html).

```
gc = gspread.oauth(
    credentials_filename='path/to/the/credentials.json',
    authorized_user_filename='path/to/the/authorized_user.json'
)
```

It displays a login screen like:

[image]

That screen tells my enduser that my script will able to:

1. See, edit, create, and delete all of their Google Drive, and/or
2. See, edit, create, and delete all of their Google Sheet spreadsheets.

I'm pretty sure that two things will scared my end user.

Is there any 'scope' that will only give my script to a sheet that shared  to my endusers account and the access right is following what sheet owner set for each endusers.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, how about using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`? The official document says about this as follows. `Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) In his case, the script can access only the file. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful information, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The best scope to use in your case is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. This is a flexible scope that will be granted individually in a per-user basis.

Of course, if you want to be as restrictive as possible the best scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly`, but its functionality is pretty limited (as the same says, only reading and no editing).

You can read more about the different scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).

Unfortunately, you cannot get rid of the authorization screen, you can read how Google authorizes access to the APIs with `OAuth` [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).